# Using a C Library in Swift Gets Unsafe Pointers

Tags: ios, c, swift, compression

I've looked at other answers but they make no sense to me.

I am trying to add this library to my Swift project:
http://ed-von-schleck.github.io/shoco/

I followed steps 1 and two from this tutorial:
https://medium.com/swift-and-ios-writing/using-a-c-library-inside-a-swift-framework-d041d7b701d9#.r1gi4q3ri

I am able to import shoco module (yay!)

According to the API this is what the function should be:

```
size_t shoco_compress(const char * in, size_t len, char * out, size_t bufsize);
```

But my Swift project generates this editor placeholder

```
shoco_compress(in: UnsafePointer<Int8>!, len: Int, out: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>!, bufsize: Int)
```

Can someone show me how to compress a string in Swift using this library?

First time using C, any pushes in the right direction appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should definitely read [Using Swift with C API](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html). To your question, here's an example of full compress-decompress cycle:

```
let str = "Hello world"

let inCStr = str.cString(using: .utf8)!

var compressedStr = [Int8](repeating: 0, count: 128)
let compressedStrLen = shoco_compress(inCStr, inCStr.count - 1, &compressedStr, compressedStr.count - 1)

var decompressedStr = [Int8](repeating: 0, count: 128)
shoco_decompress(compressedStr, compressedStrLen, &decompressedStr, decompressedStr.count - 1)

let str2 = String(cString: decompressedStr)
print(str2) // Hello world
```